# App Engine SDK PIL error

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I am developing Python application for Google App Engine on MacOS and I am having troubles trying to setup PIL for local development. I am running Python 2.5 in virtualenv and I also installed PIL 1.1.7 in the virtualenv using pip:

```
pip install PIL
```

I can import it in python interpreter and everything seems ok, but when it is used by the App Engine SDK, the following error is raised:

```
File "/Users/user/Development/src/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 564, in _save
SystemError: Parent module 'PIL' not loaded
```

It appears that this error occurs when PIL imports ICCProfile, but it should also be caught by the except and handled properly. Here is the code from PngImagePlugin.py:

```
try:
    import ICCProfile
    p = ICCProfile.ICCProfile(im.info["icc_profile"])
    name = p.tags.desc.get("ASCII", p.tags.desc.get("Unicode", p.tags.desc.get("Macintosh", p.tags.desc.get("en", {}).get("US", "ICC Profile")))).encode("latin1", "replace")[:79]
except ImportError:
    name = "ICC Profile"
```

The suggestion I got, when searching for the solution, was that I should create PIL.pth file with a path to PIL, but this file already exists in the virtualenv in site-packages folder and the content of the file is:

```
PIL
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to fix it or what else could I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) instead of PIL.

### Update 1

See this thread http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-image-sig/6543/

Comment: I tried, but development server raises the following error: NotImplementedError: Unable to find the Python PIL library.  Please view the SDK documentation for details about installing PIL on your system.

Comment: OFC you need to remove PIL first as they clash.

Comment: Anyway, your traceback shows that your PIL installation is totally broken. Instead of having a structure like "site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py" it should be "site-packages/PIL-1.1.7/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py". Thus, always use Pillow :D

Comment: I uninstalled PIL before installing Pillow and then received the before mentioned error.

Comment: PIL installation folder is the default folder created by pip install, I haven't changed it.

Comment: It does not necessarily even uninstall correctly. Try recreating the virtualenv too.

Comment: I just commented out some code in PIL as suggested in the thread you provided and it works now.