# google app engine: "could not initialize images API" even though PIL is installed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to get google app engine (GAE) up and running on a shared linux workstation. Using the standard python distribution provided by the administrators, almost everything worked just fine, except the PIL module wasn't compiled with zlib support, which breaks my web app, so I decided to do a custom build of Python in my home dir so that I could control Python and py packages. Python compiled just fine and PIL compiled just fine with both jpeg and zlib support. However, when I try to run GAE using my new Python, it complains that PIL is not available.

Here are the outputs from my builds:

python

```
% /path/to/custom/python/bin/python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 27 2013, 11:17:33) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

PIL

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.5 (default, Jun 27 2013, 11:17:33)
              [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in my new Python build, I can import PIL just fine:

```
% /path/to/custom/python/bin/python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 27 2013, 11:17:33) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL
>>>
```

Oh, and the relevant part in my `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: "1.1.7"
```

but when I fire up GAE, it complains about PIL not being available:

```
% /path/to/custom/python/bin/python dev_appserver.py ~/Dropbox/personal_website-dev
INFO     2013-06-27 18:05:07,273 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-06-27 18:05:07,671 sdk_update_checker.py:272] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2013-06-27 18:05:07,705 api_server.py:314] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-06-27 18:05:07,711 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:57893
INFO     2013-06-27 18:05:08,021 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-06-27 18:05:08,026 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

I have added /path/to/custom/python/bin as the first item in my PATH, so I really don't understand what GAE is making a big fuss about. I can import PIL. Why can't GAE?

Comment: Google App Engine does not return an ImportError when attempting to start the images API, so I figure the problem is not with importing PIL but with something else entirely. I have no clue what, though, and I can't find any verbose/debugging options to the GAE dev server.

Comment: Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116977/app-engine-sdk-pil-error?rq=1) I also tried a fresh build of python using Pillow rather than PIL. This unfortunately did not help.

Comment: _Finally_, I have found a lead. I ran `ldd *.so` on the shared library objects in `/path/to/custom/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/` and discovered that some of the libraries had not linked up correctly. So I linked them at run-time by adding jpeg, tkinter, and zlib library locations to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and finally GAE quit complaining about not being able to start the images API. I will test more before closing this question.

Answer (score 1):

This google group thread says you can safely ignore it.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/gDImZqkPOp8

The relevant information:

> Please ignore that warning.  It is from the Python runtime (which also uses the dev_appserver.py) and can safely be ignored.